# How can I toggle background color and toggle slide at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle `background-color` and `slideToggle` on click. I also want a hover-over effect on all buttons. My hover-over effect stops working after the first click. I also haven't figured out a good way to toggle `background-color` as you will see by my code.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnmartin21/yLr5equc/1/). This JavaScript code doesn't work if the same button is clicked twice:

```
$('#11').show().css({'background-color':'#cccccc'});
$('#22,#33,#44,#55,#66').show().css({'background-color':'white'});
```

Also, if you have any suggestions on how to make my JavaScript code cleaner/shorter, I'd like to see them.

Comment: this should be tagged jQuery

Comment: just added that. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little clean up you can simplify this whole thing a lot:

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button')
  .on('click', function () {

    $('.button').not(this)
      .removeClass('selected')

    $('p.displayed').not($(this).next().next())
      .slideUp()
      .removeClass('displayed')

    $(this)
      .toggleClass('selected')
      .next(/*br*/).next(/*p*/)
        .slideToggle()
        .addClass('displayed')
  })

});
```

#### css

```
button.selected {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

src: https://jsfiddle.net/yLr5equc/14/ (sorry, at first I forgot to hide the previous slideDown.. this is resolved now)

Comment: Thanks! That works. Except when I click on a button to close it, it auto opens back up. Do you know why that's happening.

Comment: I fixed that. That was a mid version

Comment: Nice solution, I have only one note: for this type of content is ideal to use description list (<dl> + <dt> + <dd>). :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the style defined in CSS has been overridden by jQuery-added inline style, therefore in `.button:hover`, add `!important` to `background-color` to make it the highest priority.

```
.button:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

**Updated solution**: https://jsfiddle.net/yLr5equc/17/

No more `!important` as I answered above. I created the class `.selected` for `.button` and toggle it instead of inserting the style inline.

```
.button.selected {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

I also have refactored the scripts, now shorter and work more effectively.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $next = $(this).next(".slide");
    if($next.hasClass("opening")) {
      $this.removeClass("selected");
      $next.slideUp("fast").removeClass("opening");
    } else {
      $this.addClass("selected");
      $this.siblings().removeClass("selected");
      $next.slideDown("fast").addClass("opening");
      $next.siblings(".slide").slideUp("fast").removeClass("opening");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed that part. Any suggestions on how to toggle the background?

Comment: @John Will it come back to white when closed?

Comment: No, if you click on a button to close it, the darker background color doesn't go away. The darker background only goes away if you click on another button.

Comment: bravo on the `.next(SELECTOR)`.. I didnt' realize that, I was using `.next().next()` ... gonna shamelessly steal this improvement

Comment: Currently, if slide 1 is open, and I click on slide 1 to close it, it will close, but the dark background remains...

Comment: actually on second look, that selector doesn't quite work the way I thought.

Answer (score 1):

> "Also, if you have any suggestions on how to my my javascipt
>   cleaning/shorter, I'm happy to listen. "

You don't need to repeat `$(document).ready(function(){}` every time for every new function/object. One `$(document).ready(function(){}` can store all your javascript/jquery code. That will shorten your code alot and make it less messy.

Like I did here: https://jsfiddle.net/yLr5equc/3/

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I could do that.